# Knex cast column content to text for joining

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

My countryDetails table looks thus:

| id | details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["United States", "United Kingdom"] |
| 2 | ["United States", "Germany"] |

My business table looks thus:

| id | countries |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["United States", "United Kingdom"] |
| 2 | ["United States", "United Kingdom"] |
| 3 | ["United States", "Germany"] |

My intention is to write a query that left joins businesses table to countryDetails table. I am using knex to make the query but it throws an error:

I am able to easily join tables that don't have their content in array format like these tables do. I think casting the values as text should work but I don't know how to do that using knex.

Here is my query:

```js
const query = knex("countryDetails")
    .select("*")
    .leftJoin("businesses", "countryDetails.details", "businesses.countries")
    .limit(1);
```

And here is the error:

```js
select * from "countryDetails" left join "businesses" on "businesses"."countries" = "countryDetails"."details" limit $1 - operator does not exist: json = json
```

How do I join the tables without it throwing errors using knex please?

Comment: Knex doesn't have casting built in, it seems, so you'll have to use `joinRaw`:

`.joinRaw('left join businesses on countryDetails.details::text = businesses.countries::text')`